# spinner setOnItemSelectedListener not working

Tags: android, spinner

I have open a spinner on button click. 
Now when I select an item of spinner, my setOnItemSelectedListener is not fired. Only the spinner gets closed on selecting an item.

The code is below:-

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(activity);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity,"Selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            final CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(
                    activity);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem in line

```
final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(activity);
```

Our spinner have modifer "final", try to declare our spinner as a field.
Example:

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    Spinner spinner;
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        spinner = new Spinner(activity);
        ...
    }
});
```